# Get list of Address Book Contacts and Import into iPhone and iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, contacts, addressbook

I am building an app that uses the iPhone AddressBook extensively.  I unfortunately only have a few contacts loaded on my device and even less in my iPhone simulator and Mac.  Does anyone know any sources/files/etc where I can get a huge list of Address Book contacts that I can import into my device and simulator to do performance based tests?

NOTE:
I appreciate the answers about how to import vcf's onto the iPhone, but more importantly: I am looking for a place where i can download 10K or so contacts/vcf's/similar format?  or maybe a random VCF generator?

Answer (score 1):

export them all as as vcf file using `ABPersonCreateVCardRepresentationWithPeople` (e.g. from your main machine)
alternatively look on google.. but thats really off topic for SO. Point is: get a vcf file

then import that data using `ABPersonCreateWithVCardRepresentation` in an app that runs in the simulator

Answer (score 0):

Building up on Daij-Djan's answer, since this is the approach I use and it doesn't require any code:

Though you mention the mac, as a last resort, if using a windows PC, you can add contacts vcf to your user directory\contacts folder, then have iTunes sync them. Once you sync them with your device they should be in your device. The contacts can be from external software like Microsoft outlook or any sort of exported contacts.